# Windows Server 2008 - Is it possible to allow traffic by MAC address

Tags: windows-firewall

I need to be able to access my webservers from outside my office and don't want to update the IP every time my dynamic IP changes.  Is it possible to create an allow rule by MAC address?

Thanks!

-Mike D

Comment: Your mac address is not something that is normally send through normal internet traffic.  Why don't you use a dns provider so you can connect to a domain instead of a ip addrss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware addresses (mac addresses) are the [layer 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) addressing system.  The layer 2 protocol, usually Ethernet, including headers like the source and destination mac address is stripped as soon as that frame is forwarded by a router.

So your computer mac address will never be seen by a computer unless you are directly connected to the same LAN.

What you probably need to do is setup a VPN that uses some form of strong authentication.  Then simply permit traffic that comes from your VPN.